# Build full joint probability distribution from partial joint probability distribution

Tags: probability

Please help me to verify my thoughts:

Suppose we have 4 boolean variables $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ that represent some events (true if happens, false if not).
We observed 3 outcomes, with events happens in next order:

- $A$ then $B$ then $C$ with $P(A_T,B_T,C_T)=.5$
- $A$ then $B$ with $P(A_T,B_T)=.3$
- $B$ then $D$ with $P(B_T,D_T)=.2$

Other combination we not observed so they probability will be zero.

Here we have kind a *partial joint probability distribution* (**Does this correct name?**), where $A$ and $C$ joined over $B$, but $A$ and $D$ is not joined.

We know that ($A$ then $B$) and ($B$ then $D$) happens, so we can assume that ($A$ then $B$ then $D$) is also possible (**Can we actually assume this or it will be incorrect in terms of probability theory?**).

To find the $P(A_T,B_T,D_T)$ we need to build *full joint probability distribution*, so for this:

Unnormalized: $P_u(A_T,B_T,D_T) = (P(A_T,B_T) + P(A_T,B_T,C_T)) * P(B_T,D_T) = (.3 + .5) * .2 = .16$

Normalized: $P_n(A_T,B_T,C_T) = \frac{P(A_T,B_T,C_T)}{P(A_T,B_T,C_T) + P_u(A_T,B_T,D_T)} = \frac{.5}{.5 + .16} ≈ .76$

And normalized: $P_n(A_T,B_T,D_T) = \frac{P_u(A_T,B_T,D_T)}{P(A_T,B_T,C_T) + P_u(A_T,B_T,D_T)} = \frac{.16}{.5 + .16} ≈ .24$

**Does this calculation looks valid in terms of probability theory?**

Thanks you!

Comment: Do you have $P(A_T,B_T)=0.3$ or $P(A_T,B_T,C_F,D_F)=0.3$? and similarly for the others.  Otherwise $P(A_T,B_T,C_T)>P(A_T,B_T)$ looks wrong.

Comment: @Henry yes it is:
$P(A_T,B_T,C_T,D_F)=.5$, 
$P(A_T,B_T, C_F,D_F)=.3$, 
$P(A_F,B_T,C_F,D_T)=.2$, 
just wrote in short manner.